# Implementing filters using dictionary packaging - Error: filter_queryset() missing 3 required positional arguments

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am trying to optimize my filter code using dictionary packaging, bt i am getting the following error:

```
filter_queryset() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'industry', 'instructor', and 'mediaType'
```

views.py

```
class CourseList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Course.objects.all()
        if(self.request.query_params):
            queryParams = self.request.query_params
            filterParams= queryParams.dict()
            queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset, **filterParams)
            # if(queryParams.get('industry', None)):
            #     queryset = queryset.filter(industry=queryParams.get('industry', None))
            # if(queryParams.get('instructor', None)):
            #                 queryset = queryset.filter(instructor=queryParams.get('instructor', None))
            # if(queryParams.get('mediaType', None)):
            #                 queryset = queryset.filter(course_media__media_type=queryParams.get('mediaType', None))
        return queryset

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset, industry, instructor, mediaType):
        queryset.filter(industry=industry).filter(instructor=instructor).filter(course_media__media_type=mediaType)
        return queryset
```

url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/authenticator/course/?industry=IT&instructor=5&mediaType=mp4

Debugger:

```
> c:\......\views.py(200)filter_queryset()

-> queryset.filter(industry=industry).filter(instructor=instructor).filter(course_media__media_type=mediaType)
(Pdb) queryset
<QuerySet [<Course: Course: lkjhh>, <Course: Course: lkjkj>]>

(Pdb) industry
'IT'

(Pdb) instructor
'5'

(Pdb) mediaType
'mp4'

(Pdb) self
<authenticator.views.CourseList object at 0x0466C890>

(Pdb) n
> c:\users\cherry\envs\projects\indiaclap\authenticator\views.py(201)filter_queryset()
-> return queryset

(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\users\cherry\envs\projects\indiaclap\authenticator\views.py(201)filter_queryset()-><QuerySet [<C...urse: lkjkj>]>
-> return queryset

(Pdb) queryset
<QuerySet [<Course: Course: lkjhh>, <Course: Course: lkjkj>]>

(Pdb) c
```

What am I missing here, because when I debug the `filter_queryset` method I can see that all the the three filter values are being populated well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is bcoz I had used the name filter_queryset which is a predefined finction in django thus overriding it wrongly. Changing the name of the function cleared the reported error, though i ran into some other errors later